# Matlab not recognizing Kinect

Tags: matlab, kinect

I am trying to connect my Kinect to MATLAB. I've installed all the necessary toolboxes and drivers but it can't seem to connect to it. I am running Windows 8.1. This is the code I'm using to check if it is connected:

```
info = imaqhwinfo('kinect');
```

and I get back:

```
info = 

       AdaptorDllName: 'C:\MATLAB\SupportPackages\R...'
    AdaptorDllVersion: '4.7 (R2014a)'
          AdaptorName: 'kinect'
            DeviceIDs: {1x0 cell}
           DeviceInfo: [1x0 struct]
```

Comment: Is it listed in the windows device manager?

Comment: yeah its listed in device manager